# Restrict email address to one top level domain (TLD) only?

Tags: php

How can I restrict email addresses to .edu only, in the following code?

```
function ValidateEmail($email) {
    global $debug;
    if($debug)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return preg_match("/^[^\s]+@[^\s]+.[^\s]+$/", $email);
}
```

Comment: @DannyBeckett: the OS tried with `preg_match("/^[^\s]+@[^\s]+.[^\s]+$/", $email);` and he want to only match emails with .edu at the end! nothing bad here!!!

Answer (score 4):

PHP 5.2 or above check with this code

```
function validateEmailAddress($email) {
  return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && preg_match('/@.+\.edu/', $email);
}
```

Comment: since it's a syntaxically valid email, why not have the final test as just "&& preg_match('/\.edu$/', $email)" instead?

Comment: i like the approach but not the regex. :P `'/\.edu$/'` should be used instead

Answer (score 0):

well, your regexp to validate any email is very primitive and incomplete, but assuming that's good enough for you, you only need to add ".edu" explicitly at the end instead of [^\s]+, like this:

```
return preg_match("/^[^\s]+@[^\s]+\\.edu$/", $email);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very novice at reg-expressions.  But you can see after the period that there is this block: `[^\s]+`.  The carrot (^) refers to not, the \s refers to whitespace (tabs, newlines, spaces), and the + says match unlimited of these characters until you reach the next part of the regex (which happens to be the end).  This means that after the `.` in the domain of an email, your script is matching infinite non-whitespace characters.  This means both `example@test.com` and `example@test.comcomcomcomcomcom` would work, but `example@test.c om` would not.  Replacing this `[^\s]+` with `edu` should work.

```
function ValidateEmail($email) {
    global $debug;
    if($debug)
        return TRUE;
    else
        return preg_match("/^[^\s]+@[^\s]+.edu$/", $email);
}
```

If this does not work (because I am very poor at regexp), I would incorporate PHP's substr().

```
function ValidateEmail($email) {
    global $debug;
    if($debug)
        return TRUE;
    else {
        if(substr($email,-4) != '.edu'))
             return false;
        else   // ends in .edu, check for valid email
             return preg_match("/^[^\s]+@[^\s]+.[^\s]+$/", $email);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    preg_match("/^[^\s]+@[^\s]+.[^\s]+$/", $email);
```

In this pattern, the .edu should be placed at the end of the pattern:

```
    preg_match("/^[^\s]+@[^\s]+(.[^\s]+)*(\.edu)$/", $email);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
function ValidateEmail($email) { 

    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)  && ( substr($email ,-4) == ".edu")){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```